# Call activity using intent method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I know that Android OS need paramterles constructor to recreate Activity and i could use bundle to pass some arguments if required as follows:

```
private void OpenOtherActivityWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
      Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(ThirdActivity));
      Dog mydog = new Dog("mydogName");
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.PutSerializable("mydoggy", mydog);
      nextActivity.PutExtra("RowID", Convert.ToString(10));
      nextActivity.PutExtras(bundle);
      StartActivity(nextActivity);
}

[Activity(Label = "ThirdActivity")]
 public class ThirdActivity : Activity
 {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.third);

            //Receive values if any from previous activity
            if (!Intent.HasExtra("mydoggy")) return;
            Dog tryme = (Dog)Intent.GetSerializableExtra("mydoggy");
            if (!Intent.HasExtra("RowID")) return;
            string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("RowID") ?? "0";
        }
}
```

Nevertheless is it possible to create static method which would return intent for me from given parameters like?:

```
static Intent CreateIntent(Dog dog, int rowID)
```

If so could someone show me then how it could look like as opposite to whati show in my code please.

Comment: change `CreateIntent(Dog dog, int rowID)` to `CreateIntent(Context context, Dog dog, int rowID)` move your code from `OpenOtherActivityWindow_Click` into `CreateIntent` remove  `StartActivity`, return `nextActivity` instead `this` use `context` put `CreateIntent` into `ThirdActivity` ... replace strings with constant strings

Comment: @Selvin i have one more question i got now inside OpenOtherActivityWindow_Clic as follows:         Intent nextActivity = ThirdActivity.CreateIntent(this, new Dog(), 10 );
            StartActivity(nextActivity);
           string a=  nextActivity.myDog;
           string b= nextActivity.myText;

nevetheless myDog and myText is not accessible even i they are as public proeprties of ThirdActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of your `ThirdActivity`, but I could achieve the similar function by creating a simple demo.
You can check the code here.

```
   [Activity(Label = "MovieDetailActivity")]
public class MovieDetailActivity : Activity
{
    public  TextView textView;

    public  static MovieModel mMoviemodel;// define your model here

    public  static int mRowID;  // define a int variable mRowID


    public  static Intent createIntent(Context context, MovieModel movie, int rowID)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MovieDetailActivity));
        //Pass parameters here

        mMoviemodel = movie; 
        mRowID = rowID;

        return intent;
    }


  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.detaillayout);

        textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.info_textview);

        textView.Text = "movie name:" + mMoviemodel.mMovieName + " text = " + mRowID;

    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
   // pass your Object model
    StartActivity( MovieDetailActivity.createIntent(this, movie,10));
```

Comment: i heard its god to use mvvm is there any good easy tutorial how to create simple app using mvvm?

Comment: For xamarin android, there are a lot of tutorials in Google:https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enSG818SG818&ei=D6xSXP_CB8eN8wWv4IOwBg&q=xamarin+android+mvvmlight&oq=xamarin+android+mvvmlight&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i10i30j0i30.46878.46878..47119...0.0..0.215.215.2-1......0....1..gws-wiz.JFKHU4TqCtI

Comment: You can check the tutorial: https://mallibone.com/post/xamarinandroid-and-mvvm-light-bindings    ,and sample code is also available in this link.